# Showing a modal dialog and getting results

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, modal-dialog

I have a static `WindowService` class which helps me to create new windows and modal dialogs.
So far, what I have is this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Opens a new window of type <paramref name="newWindowType"/> and closes the <paramref name="oldWindow"/>
/// </summary>
/// <param name="oldWindow">The window which should be closed (Usually the current open window)</param>
/// <param name="newWindowType">The type of the new window to open</param>
public static void ShowNewWindow(Window oldWindow, Type newWindowType)
{
    ((Window)Activator.CreateInstance(newWindowType)).Show();
    oldWindow.Close();
}
```

My viewmodel raises an event and the view is subscribed to it. In the event handler in the view, it calls `WindowService.ShowNewWindow(this,The type here)`. This works fine.
  My modal dialog creating method will also work in a similar way. The only difference is that the information will be returned to the view (At the event handler) so the view will have to pass that information to the view model in code explicitly. This violates mvvm pattern and I don't know how to make the viewmodel wait for the view to return the value after the event is raised.
Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: I believe that you had overcomplicated things. You've missed the important thing: `the only difference is that the information will be returned to the view (At the event handler) so the view will have to pass that information to the view model in code explicitly` Why is it so?

Comment: Because I am calling the service methods at the event handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, this ol' chestnut.

There are **many** different variations on how to achieve this, however here's my two cents.

The main ideas here are to ensure that your `View` and `View Model` do not know about each other, therefore your `View` should not subscribe to an event in your `View Model`, and your `View Model` should not directly call your service and provide a view `Type`.

---

### Don't use events, use Commands instead

My recommendation would be to use `ICommand` implementations instead of relying on a static service class, for the reason that your class will always have a dependency to this service, and also as soon as you send the view `Type` to this service, then the MVVM pattern is lost.

So, firstly, we need some kind of command which will open a window of a given `Type`, here's what I have come up with:

```
public class OpenWindowCommand : ICommand
{
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        TypeInfo p = (TypeInfo)parameter;

        return p.BaseType == typeof(Window);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        if (parameter == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("TargetWindowType");

        //Get the type.
        TypeInfo p = (TypeInfo)parameter;
        Type t = p.BaseType;

        if (p.BaseType != typeof(Window))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("parameter is not a Window type");

        //Create the window.
        Window wnd = Activator.CreateInstance(t) as Window;

        OpenWindow(wnd);
    }

    protected virtual void OpenWindow(Window wnd)
    {
        wnd.Show();
    }
}
```

The class inherits from `ICommand` and specifies the implementation which accepts a `Type`, which represents the desired `View` that we want to open. Notice I have marked a method as `virtual`, I'll explain that part in a moment.

Here's how we can make use of this command in our `View Model`:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public OpenWindowCommand OpenWindowCommand { get; private set; }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        OpenWindowCommand = new OpenWindowCommand();
    }

    ...
}
```

Now we've created the command, we simply need to bind a `Button` to it:

```
<Button Content="Open Window"
        Command="{Binding OpenWindowCommand}"
        CommandParameter="{x:Type local:MyWindow}"/>
```

One thing to note here is that I am using `x:Type` as the `CommandParameter`, this is the `Window` that will be created when this command gets executed.

---

### But what about a dialog?

What we achieved above is only **half** of the requirement, we now need something that will display a **dialog** and output the result to our `View Model`, this isn't so tricky as we have most of what we need already in our existing `OpenWindowCommand`.

First, we need to create the command:

```
public class ShowDialogCommand : OpenWindowCommand
{
    private Action _PreOpenDialogAction;
    private Action<bool?> _PostOpenDialogAction;

    public ShowDialogCommand(Action<bool?> postDialogAction)
    {
        if (postDialogAction == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("postDialogAction");

        _PostOpenDialogAction = postDialogAction;
    }

    public ShowDialogCommand(Action<bool?> postDialogAction, Action preDialogAction)
        : this(postDialogAction)
    {
        if (preDialogAction == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("preDialogAction");

        _PreOpenDialogAction = preDialogAction;
    }

    protected override void OpenWindow(System.Windows.Window wnd)
    {
        //If there is a pre dialog action then invoke that.
        if (_PreOpenDialogAction != null)
            _PreOpenDialogAction();

        //Show the dialog
        bool? result = wnd.ShowDialog();

        //Invoke the post open dialog action.
        _PostOpenDialogAction(result);
    }
}
```

We're making use of our `OpenWindowCommand` by inheriting from it and using it's implementation instead of having to copy all of it into our new class. The command takes an `Action` which is a reference to a method in your `View Model`, you have the option of defining an action **before** or **after** (or both) a dialog is displayed.

The next step is to change our `View Model` so it creates this new command:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public OpenWindowCommand OpenWindowCommand { get; private set; }
    public ShowDialogCommand ShowDialogCommand { get; private set; }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        OpenWindowCommand = new OpenWindowCommand();
        ShowDialogCommand = new ShowDialogCommand(PostOpenDialog);
    }

    public void PreOpenDialog()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void PostOpenDialog(bool? dialogResult)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The usage of this command is practically the same as before, but it just references a different command:

```
<Button Content="Open Window"
        Command="{Binding ShowDialogCommand}"
        CommandParameter="{x:Type local:MyWindow}"/>
```

And there you have it, everything is loosely coupled, the only real dependencies here are that your `View Model` depends on your `ICommand` classes.

---

### Some final words

The `ICommand` classes that I have created act as a controller between the `View` and the `View Model` to ensure that they do not know about each other, and keeps the MVVM pattern enforced.

Like I said at the beginning of this answer, there are many ways of which this can be achieved, however I hope you are now a little more enlightened.

Comment: Thank you so much. This helped a lot :)

Comment: But how should I close the view while opening a new view now?

Comment: You can use `Application.Current.Windows` or `Application.Current.MainWindow` to get at the windows that are currently being displayed. Some variations on the `ICommand` classes would need to handle these. It's not *perfect*, but it's fine to take some technical debt for this task. If you really want to take this further, consider creating a `Custom Control` which could have a `WindowToClose` dependency property, your command can then use this property to close the desired window. Again, you'll have to experiment and see what works best.

Comment: Thanks, I modified the command to take in an object as a command parameter. This object will have the sender view, new view type, and additional information to pass to the new view's constructor. It works great :)

Comment: I'm playing around with your solution and have created a custom `MarkupExtension` to contain type, window owner and other stuff, which i pass on as the `CommandParameter`. I'm just wondering why the ViewModel decides if it's going to be a window or dialog (via the created command instance)?

Comment: The view model doesn't know if it's going to be a Window or a Dialog, it's up to whoever wants to *use* the view model to decide how it needs to present it. For example, you might want the window to be opened to block the thread until it returns, in this case, you want it to be a dialog. The commands I demonstrated are simply a means of opening windows/dialogs from a view model, exactly how your view model behaves depends on whether the view model that calls these commands wants the view model to behave as a window, or as a dialog. I hope that made some sense.