# Dialog windows MVVM way

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

We're in desktop WPF world. Let's imagine the following scenario (~ user story).

**Window A** is a dialog window for adding or editing entity A in the database. One of the fields is a reference to other entity. For user's convenience, there's "Add entity B" button.

When user presses this button, **Window B** is being displayed, which serves similar role - adding or editing entities B. When user presses OK, entity is being added to the database and returned, such that it may be used by **Window A** to set it automatically in some field.

Now let's discuss technicalities. `WindowA` is backed by `WindowAViewModel`. Pressing button results in calling `WindowAViewModel.CreateBEntity` method. And then what?

- I cannot simply create instance of **Window B**, because that would create dependency from `WindowAViewModel` to `WindowB` and that's something I don't want to do.
- `WindowAViewModel` may call `WindowA` via interface, say `IWindowAAccess` asking for new `EntityB`. Then `WindowA` may instantiate `WindowB` and then receive newly created entity and pass it back to `WindowAViewModel`. That would create dependency between `WindowA` and `EntityB`, but I guess that's acceptable. Or not?
- `WindowAViewModel` may ask some `IDialogService` to perform the whole action. And then the implementation, `DialogService` would create `WindowB` and perform the whole operation, returning `EntityB`. But is it acceptable to create dependencies from services to specific views?

What is the proper way of solving this issue?

---

**Edit:** [Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32739791) discusses the similar issue. However, I have some possible solutions, that may or may not be valid and I'd like to know, whether they may be used or not (as the solution proposed in the discussed question seems like a little bit overkill to me).

Comment: I asked a question really similar to this and a guy gave me a quite good way using commands. You could then use generics and other stuff to make it more fancy. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32739791/showing-a-modal-dialog-and-getting-results

Comment: This is one of the reasons why I don't believe services are a good way of solving the MVVM dialog box problem. It is in fact possible to do everything using view models alone, with behaviours invoking the creation of the dialog boxes themselves. You might want to take a look at [a long article I wrote about it on the code project site](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/820324/Implementing-Dialog-Boxes-in-MVVM).

Comment: MVVM dialog boxes always cause fun, you might want to check out the implementations in these two open source projects: https://github.com/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit  and  https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro

Answer (score 0):

In the [caliburn.micro](http://caliburnmicro.com]) world, you can do this with `IWindowManager.ShowDialog(ModelView)`.

Using an IoC, inject `WindowManager` to `IWindowManager` at `Bootstrapper`, and add `IWindowManager` to your `ViewModel` constructor. Having `IWindowManager` in hands, call `ShowDialog`.

Code example:

```
public class AppBootstrapper : BootstrapperBase
{
    // ...

    protected override void Configure()
    {
        container.Singleton<IWindowManager, WindowManager>();
    }
}

public class CallingViewModel
{
    private readonly IWindowManager windowManager;

    public CallingViewModel(IWindowManager windowManager)
    {
        this.windowManager = windowManager;
    }

    public Method()
    {
        var called = new CalledViewModel();
        var result = windowManager.ShowDialog(called);

        // handle result
    }
}

public class CalledViewModel : Screen
{
    public void Ok()
    {
        TryClose(true);
    }

    public void Cancel()
    {
        TryClose(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on good way with the last point.

If you ask some `IDialogService` to create `WindowB`, you don't have to couple it with `WindowB`, because WindowB is a parameter.

```
public IDialogService {
   public bool? ShowDialog(Type dialogType); //there is no dependency to concrete dialog.
}

dialogService.ShowDialog(typeof(WindowB));
//or 
dialogService.ShowDialog(typeof(WindowBViewModel));
```

if you need to pass more information to the window, you can do one of following:

```
var dialogViewModel = new WindowBViewModel();
dialogViewModel.Parameter = parameter;
dialogService.ShowDialog(dialogViewModel);

//or
dialogService.ShowDialog(typeof(WindowBViewModel), parameter);
```

Comment: notice, that this is basically the same problem as navigation, so stay close to what you already have designed for navigation